# Reverse array, why does is work when I divide by 2?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, reverse

I have this code below which writes a word backward, I understand everything but one little detail in the for loop: for (int i = 0; i < numberOfChars /2; i++). What does the "/2" do and why does it only work with it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h> // time


void reverse(char array[], int numberOfChars) {

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfChars /2; i++) {
        char tmp;

        tmp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[numberOfChars - i - 1];
        array[numberOfChars - i - 1] = tmp;

    }
}


int main(void) {

    char word[55];
    int howMany;

    printf("Please enter a word:\n");
    scanf_s("%s", word, sizeof(word));
    printf("how many char do you want to reverse?\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &howMany);

    reverse(word, howMany);

    printf("New arr:%s\n", word);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're swapping the first half of the array with the other half. If you swapped both halves twice...

Comment: Have you tried removing the `/2` and finding out what happens? Have you tried debugging step by step (with a short word as input), and understanding why it works "neatly" with the `/2` but not without it?

Comment: @barakmanos Yeah I have, if I remove "/2" the code doesn't change anything.. Or I like someone said here, it changed twice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The division halves the array. When you track the algorithm, it swaps one from left hand side, the other is from right hand side. For even size, every number is exchanged. For odd size, same like evens except by the middle one stayed at its same place. When I encountered the algorithm, I solved it using a paper and pen. Because the way more effective to get its logic. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13465414/4990642) is the depicted explanation. *As a result, if it isn't halved, firstly reversed up to half of the array, then reversed again so stayed as same order.*

Answer (score 1):

As Ryan pointed out in a comment, if you do not include the `/2` each position in the array gets swapped twice, and goes right back to where it started. For example, if you have 5 elements, it does this:

```
  swap 0 with 4
  swap 1 with 3
  swap 2 with 2
  swap 3 with 1
  swap 4 with 0
```

By the way, I think this code gets clearer if you use two indices to iterate over the array instead of one:

```
int i=0;
int j=numberOfChars-1;
while(i < j){
    char tmp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = tmp;
    i++;
    j--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because with this code, you put the start in the end, and the end in the start of your string. So, when you run a half of the "howMany" char's your user wants to change, it has already changed it at all.